# Are the filenames created by `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory` safe for use in the command line?

Tags: python, operating-system, temporary-files

I have a python script that calls a sequence of other programs.  In between, some temporary files are created as input to these other programs.  In order not to clutter up the file system, I create all these temporary files in a temporary directory, created by `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`.

When I call the other programs using `os.system`, the command line has to include the name of the temporary directory.  My question is: Can I be sure that the name of the temporary directory only contains "safe" characters (no `()/\?*` etc.)?  Or do I have to escape the name in some way?

Currently, I use:

```
    dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
    dirname = dir.name + "/"
    os.system("lp_solve -S1 " + dirname + "test.lp")
```

Comment: you can assume the tmp directory is the systems temp directory so it would have no special characters .... that said someone could change it in theory to point wherever ... also sometimes sysadmins lock down the temp dir ... (only if they are jerks)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Don't confuse `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` with `tempfile.gettempdir()`.  The latter gives the default temp directory of the operating system (usually `/tmp` on Linux), while the first creates a new temporary directory (usually a subdirectory of `/tmp` with a "random name").  But you have a point: If the sys admin does funny things, the base directory itself may contain funny characters.

Comment: If you're worried about "not nice characters" (the name will be filesystem suitable), then instead of building a string and using `os.system`, then I imagine your concern will be alleviated by using `subprocess.call(['lp_solve', '-S1', dirname + 'test.lp'])` - that'll allow auto-escaping of the parameters when calling as appropriate - is that what you're effectively asking?

Comment: @JonClements Maybe.  What would `subprocess.call(['lp_solve', '-S1', 'A test.lp'])` do?  Would it call `lp_solve` on the file `A test.lp`?

Comment: @jarauh I imagine it'd be the same as typing `lp_solve -S1 "A test.lp"` in your shell - the docs state the behaviour fairly well.

Comment: @JonClements I just checked in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), and there is an example for `run` (though not for `call`) that worries me: `subprocess.run("exit 1", shell=True, check=True)`

Comment: There's a distinct difference between `shell=True` (which is similar to using `os.system` which we're trying to avoid) - which literally takes a single string and passes it to the shell as is and `shell=False` (the specific behaviour for `subprocess.call`) which attempts to build a single suitably escaped string from components... what exactly is your concern?

Comment: @JonClements I want the string quoted, and I just checked that `subprocess.call()` without `shell=True` works as expected.  Thanks!